# PID error on mysql.server start?

Tags: mysql, macos, pid, homebrew

I've just tried installing MySQL using homebrew (on Mac OS X 10.6), but I've run across an issue at the first hurdle. When trying to manually start the server (mysql.server start), I get the following error:

```
. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure of which error logs or configuration files to check, as I've never installed MySQL in this way before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I ran into this same problem when installing via homebrew.  Make sure you run these commands (which are listed during install but easy to miss):

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That seems to have done the trick, prior to performing the following action: sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local

Comment: This outputs exceptions: 
`2016-05-31 10:47:27 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2016-05-31 10:47:27 [ERROR]   The data directory needs to be specified.`

Comment: It works on MYSQL 5.7.13(Installed via Homebrew).

`unset TMPDIR && cd /usr/local/var/mysql/ && rm * && mysqld --initialize`

Note that will clean you data.

Comment: Thanks @Kixoms. I modified your code to `set -e TMPDIR; cd /usr/local/var/mysql/; sudo rm -rf *; sudo mysqld --initialize` for Fish. Then just to be safe did `brew uninstall mysql`

Comment: I don't have the directory `/usr/local/var/mysql/`.

Comment: I've built MySQL from source, didn't know `mysqld` would have an `initialize` option, but it works great when you have to do the 'plumbing' yourself!

Answer (score 19):

You probably need to ensure that you're running mysql as the `root` user -- otherwise it won't have permission to write the PID file (thus the error you're receiving).

Try this:

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

You'll be prompted for your password.  (this assumes that your user account has permissions to "sudo" -- which it should, unless it's setup as a restricted user account in OS X).

This may not be the only issue -- but it should get you to the next step anyway.

Comment: OMG! Why can't mysql simply say that "you do not have sufficient permissions". "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file" is an extremely misleading error message.

Comment: @MayankJaiswal because the reason for a PID file not being created could be another reason besides permissions.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I agree that there can be many reasons for not being able to read PID file. But why not be as specific as possible? An extreme example: your compiler tries very hard to pin point the error and not just says "Some error in file foo.py. Cant compile.". Instead, it would say "Parse Error on line 36 character 26, unexpected identifier: ';' " - isn't that sweet ?

Comment: I think you should submit a patch to the open-source repo maintainers.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue while trying to install MySQL 5.5.15 in Lion using homebrew and resolved the issue with:

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

and creating a the file ~/my.cnf

with the content:

```
 [mysqld]
   basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15
   datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
```

basedir - should be your current MySQL instalation dir
datadir - should be the location of MySQL data

You can figure out that too location by watching the make command during the "brew install mysql" searching for something like this:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql
```

Where DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = basedir and DMYSQL_DATADIR = datadir

Answer (score 6):

These following two commands should solve your issue.

```
> unset TMPDIR
> mysql_install_db --verbose --user=\`whoami\` --basedir="$(brew
--prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

Answer (score 6):

Nothing else really helped, but the following worked:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
tagir           27260   0.0  1.0  3562356 175120   ??  S     2:52PM   0:00.42 mysqld --skip-grant-tables
tagir           42704   0.0  0.0  2434840    784 s000  S+    3:04PM   0:00.00 grep mysql
$ kill 27260
# Careful! This might erase your existing data
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
$ mysqld --initialize
$ mysql.server start
```

Comment: For some reason, initializing the database, deleting it, and then initializing it again worked for me.

Comment: I searching for a while but nothing worked for me
but your answer fixed my error. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am adding this here because I encountered this problem several times after installing other software. MySQL was working fine for days, then suddenly I get this error.

It seems to happen when I install something (eg. elasticsearch or Puma web server). The MySql permissions get reverted again (back to me, and not `_mysql`). No idea why.

- MacOS Sierra
- Homebrew 1.0.5-43-g41b2df8 (2016-10-02)
- MySQL 5.7.15

So I have found that one cause of this is the permissions on the location where MySQL stores your databases, which by default is here:

```
/usr/local/var/mysql
```

If you look in that folder you will see a file

```
<your computer name>.err
```

If you look inside that file (`more` it or `cat` it) you will probably see this error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
```

If so then you know it is a permissions issue.

If you don't care, you can probably just run MySQL by just running `mysqld` (and leave that terminal open).

If you do care:

`ls -al /usr/local/var/mysql`

you will notice that the permissions are probably all set to you (your user account). This means mysql cannot mount your databases when you run it using the homebrew shortcut `sudo mysql.server start` [even though you are using sudo to run in 'admin' mode].

So, change the permissions:

```
$ sudo chown -R _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
$ sudo chmod -R o+rwx /usr/local/var/mysql
```

Then it will work.

Comment: I came to this error just after upgrading to Sierra. I tried to change permissions, but the error persist... any other idea?

Comment: You could try to reinstall mysql

Comment: It is odd... I solved the problem moving the datafiles to another path...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for whatever reason I can't comment below Immendes above, but on 10.8.2 with mySQL 5.6.10, in addition to verifying the db_install and adding the my.cnf, I also had to chown -R myusername /tmp/mysql.sock.

It appears that allowing mySQL to run under the user (as apposed to root or www as I woudl do on linux) is not the best idea in this regard (though Homebrew could update the formula -- beyond my scope and time).

Answer (score 0):

1. `brew postinstall mysql`
2. `delete document /opt/homebrew/var/mysql`
3. `brew postinstall mysql`

Comment: Please explain why this works