# After MySQL install via Brew, I get the error - The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, homebrew

Ok, I've searched all over and have spent quite a bit of my time installing, uninstalling, trying various option but without success.

I'm on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.3) and am trying to setup a Python, MySQL.

I successfully installed Python and MySQL via HomeBrew.
Python works great.

After MySQL Installation, I followed the first 2 steps - unset and the `mysql_install_db` commands.

Now, when I try to start mysql "mysql.server start", I get the following error

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Brajeshwar.local.pid).
```

- `Brajeshwar` is my username on my machine.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**EDIT 2012/09/18:**
As [pointed out by Kane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating/9704993#comment16367803_9704993), make sure the `mysql` database is properly set up before doing anything else. See “[PID error on mysql.server start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start)” for more info.

**Original answer kept for history's sake:**
It most likely *is* a permissions issue. Check `/usr/local/var/mysql/*.err`. Mine said:

```
120314 16:30:14  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
120314 16:30:14 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/janmoesen.local.pid ended
```

I also had to do this:

```
sudo chown _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/*
```

Comment: I solved the issue running: `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`

Comment: I get the same error, but I have no /usr/local/var/mysql folder :( I am also using homebrew.

Comment: See the comments of `brew info mysql` or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start) for right solution

Comment: sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql fixed the issue for me, thanks!

Comment: sudo chmod ugo+w /tmp was my solution.

Comment: sometimes ibdata isnot writable so this worked for me
 sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/*

Comment: As much as I don't like doing, `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/`, it worked.

Comment: mine was solved with sudo chown -R {my_user_name}:admin /usr/local/var/mysql55/

Comment: My issue was that skip-locking was no longer supported in v5.5 from v5.1

Answer (score 119):

I found that it was a permissions issue with the `mysql` folder.

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

solved it for me.

Comment: there is no need to make this 777

Comment: I was also searching for a long time and this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Please note I do not recommend setting anything to 777 in a production environment. This needs to be on a local install only. I would also switch it back to 755 as a minimum.

Comment: If you see error on mysql start
Warning: World-writable config file '/var/lib/mysql/none-dev/my.cnf' is ignored


Then you'll probably want to 
chmod o-w /var/lib/mysql/none-dev/my.cnf

Comment: mine was solved with sudo chown -R {my_user_name}:admin /usr/local/var/mysql55/

Comment: Only a solution that worked! this solved a OSX Catalina update issue.

Comment: `sudo` can be needed !

Comment: I'm on OSX Big Sur with MySQL 8.0.23 installed. This solved my issue

Comment: How you found that the issue is on mysql folder permission? can ou tell me

Comment: @JovylleBermudez 

```
ls -la /usr/local/var/mysql/ 
```

check the ownership and the accessability of the directory compared to the user you are running the command from.

Comment: I'm using mysql 8.0.30 - Homebrew, this solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 85):

I ended up with completely reinstalling of mysql, and it finally worked out.

**WARNING** This will remove all of your databases, so make sure to save dumps first.

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql

brew install mysql
mysqld --initialize --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
mysql.server start # no sudo!
```

Comment: I tried changing permissions in every possible way without success. Ended up following these instructions and... success :)

Comment: This is the ONLY solution I found. This should be number one

Comment: Thanks, this is the only thing that worked for me. Although I didn't have to run `mysqld --initialize --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --force` when doing the brew cleanup

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfect for me. But in my case `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` does not exist. I mean I only remove `/usr/local/var/mysql`

Comment: Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (<path>-.lightspeed.irvnca.sbcglobal.net.pid). Getting this error

Comment: Just homebrew issue

Comment: I do the same but after "mysql -uroot" I get "access denied for user root" error, as I did not set any passwords, why it is not going without password

Comment: Maybe you should put a warning besides `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql`.

Comment: Nothing worked after "brew upgrade"..this answer saved me. I have now a fresh install of mysql, works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: I, too, ended up reinstalling via Brew. It took a few goes at it, with a couple of removals, along the way, but got there in the end - just don't forget to make a dump first before you doing anything

Comment: Note, I needed to specify my version number, i.e. using `mysql@5.7`

Comment: God bless you my child. After four hours in MySQL hell this finally fixed it for me.

Comment: You saved me again.

Answer (score 35):

I had this issue on mac 10.10.5 Yosemite

What I did to solve this

`cd /usr/local/var/mysql` 
`sudo rm *.err && sudo rm *.pid` 
`sudo reboot`
`sudo mysql.server start`

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue on OS X El Capitan, here's the terminal command sequence that fixed it for me.

Delete error files (you'll have to change the path depending on your setup)

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err
```

Find the info for the mysql process that's still running and kill it:

```
ps -A | grep -m1 mysql | awk '{print $1}' | sudo xargs kill -9
```

Now restart MySQL:

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 17):

November, 2014: If you're getting this error on MySQL 5.6.x on Mac OS X Mavericks or Yosemite and want to use MySQL with PHP locally (/tmp/mysql.sock is where PHP PDO expects to find the sock file), here is what fixed it for me:

1) Uncomment the default homebrew config file lines and edit as below

```
$ sudo vi /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/my.cnf
...
basedir = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21
datadir = /usr/local/var/mysql
port = 3306
server_id = <UNIQUE_NUMBER_HERE_OR_LEAVE_COMMENTED_OUT>
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file = /usr/local/var/mysql/[BOXNAME].local.pid
....
```

BOXNAME is what you have in your System Prefs -> Network as the unique id for your computer on the network.

2) Set permissions on all the files in the mysql datadir. These were all owned by [my_username]. MySQL is very picky about this and refuses to create the pid file unless it (the user _mysql) owns the directory.

```
$ sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

3) Start MySQL using the bash helper/wrapper script:

```
$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

Hope that helps. If the above doesn't work for you, try to run the mysqld_safe binary manually in the Cellar/mysql/VERSION_/bin/ directory and check what the settings are (if it runs)

```
sudo /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

If that runs, you can

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

and see something like

```
[username]  6881   0.0  2.7  3081392 454836   ??  S     8:52AM   0:00.54 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/lib/plugin --verbose --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/BOXNAME.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/BOXNAME.local.pid
```

I'm not sure why that worked for me but it shows you where I got the my.cnf config file options from. You can also use the command line options to try to troubleshoot when starting mysqld manually.

If you do run manage to run MySQL server using mysqld_safe, you may have to do this to shut it down before trying the mysql.server bash helper. Resist the urge to kill -9 [PID] because you can corrupt your data.

```
mysqladmin -uroot shutdown
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks - mine was solved with sudo chown -R {my_user_name}:admin /usr/local/var/mysql55/

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: This solved my issue in MAC os 10.11.3  (after changing mode to 777 of the mysql dir)

Comment: This means Read Write Execute, or full rights to all users to that folder and (-R) all files and folders under that folder.
For detailed explanation, please take a look at the following link:
https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me on 10.12.2 :

```
$ rm /usr/local/var/mysql/*.err
```

then

```
$ brew services restart mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly it is a permissions issue. Try to 'touch' and 'chmod' the pid file or the folder the file is held in.

Comment: Nope. I even tried chmod 777 to see if that solves the problem but nothing. Same ERROR.

Comment: Did you try to chmod 777 the mysql directory and deleting the pid file and restarting MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I started server as sudo once and then tried to restart as a local user.

Here mysql was not able to write to '.err' file owned by root.
I had to remove that file and restart the server:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/var/mysql/*.err
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (OSX)

Step 1:
`ps -aux | grep mysql`

Then kill the 4 digits PID number

Step 2: `kill 1965`

Step 3: `mysql.server start`

Or having hard time to locate those PID numbers, try this below

Step 1 again: `ps -aux | grep mysql`

Step 2 again: `killall`

Step 3 again: `mysql.server start`

Comment: ps: No user named 'x'

Answer (score 2):

I’ve got a similar problem with MySQL on a Mac (Mac Os X Could not startup MySQL Server. Reason: 255 and also “ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file”). After a long trial and error process, finally in order to restore the file permissions, I’ve just do that:

launch the Disk Utilities.app
choose my drive on the left panel
click on the “Repair disk permissions” button

This did the trick for me. Hoping this can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Find usr/local/var/mysql/your_computer_name.local.err file and understand the more information about error

Location : /usr/local/var/mysql/your_computer_name.local.err

It's probably problem with permissions

1. Find if mysql is running and kill it

> ps -ef | grep mysql
>
> kill -9 PID

where PID is second column value
 2. check ownership of mysql

> ls -laF /usr/local/var/mysql/

```
if it is owned by root, change it mysql or your user name
```

> sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/

Answer (score 2):

Please check the log , you will get more detailed information .

Use the below command to tail the error log

```
tail -100 /usr/local/var/mysql/<user_name>.local.err
```

For me , one of the directory is missing , once created the server has started .

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mariadb)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

1. Go to your mysql installation directory
2. `sudo chmod -R 777 data`
3. Then go back one directory
4. `cd support-files/`
5. `sudo ./mysql.server start`

After that the server started running.

But the problem with this method is that I have to repeat this every time I want to start the mysql now. Don't know why it started behaving like this suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Linux, but the cause is relevant to any mysql installation.  In my case, the server was crashing before startup was complete and the pid file updated.  The error messages were seen when starting up mysqld directly instead of via "service mysql start".

In my case, the cause was the partition where the log files were located being full.  Removing log files permitted mysql to start again.  To test for this issue, go to the location of your mysql activity logs, and do `df .`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded your mysql installation to 8.x, check if your previous version is supported for [upgradation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html).

If not, mysql will not work! Uninstall your mysql along with all configuration files in `/usr/local/var/mysql` (remove the whole folder). Reinstall mysql.

NOTE: reinstalling might lead to loss of data.

Answer (score 1):

The key takeaway is to check the .err file, by default on Mac OSX it's in `/usr/local/var/mysql`.

That log filed revealed to me that I had to delete the following files:

```
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
```

Running MySQL with `mysql.start` worked successfully after that. Note that deleting those files will likely causes data loss.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be actually being show because mysql is already started.  Try to see the current status by:

```
mysql.server status
```

Comment: I've always solved this deleting the log files, but `ps` did in fact show mysql processes. I killed everything re-ran `mysql.server restart` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is file permission problem.
Check disk permissions and repair.

**Osx => Cmd+Space => Disk Utilty => Verify Disk Permissions.**

Verify completed after Repair Disk Permissions.
mysql.server start command is worked succesfuly.

Comment: This worked for me. Please try this before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

But the situation was, every time i try to enter:

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

a file named `localhost.pid` is created instead of `iMax0.local.pid` which was stated in the error:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/iMax0.local.pid).
```

Solution that works for me was copying `localhost.pid` and renaming it to `iMax0.local.pid`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. But the following commands saved me.

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar
sudo chown _mysql mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution on OSX El Capitan was:

```
sudo chmod ugo+w /tmp
```

It was broken suddenly.

The error was:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

and the log showed:

```
Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
```

It might also be helpful to note, that under OSX there is no `my.cnf` file by default and not needed by default, which I did not know. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo mysql.server restart
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. However, I simply did `sudo mysql.server start` and it worked nicely.

Also, for me, it did NOT show permissions issue in *.err file.

Answer (score 0):

all solutions above doesn't work for me.
but they give me some clues to fix this error.

> mysql.server start ----error The server quit without updating PID file

I installed mysql@5.7 on my macbook mojave with homebrew

> brew install mysql@5.7

mysql error log located in /usr/local/var/mysql/IU.lan.err,there is one line in it:
Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

after trying many posts in goole search engine,I turned to baidu
https://blog.csdn.net/xhool/article/details/52398042
inspired by this post,I found the solution:

> rm /usr/local/var/mysql/*
>
> mysqld --initialize

a random password for root user will be shown in bash.
but the command mysql -uroot -p[theRandomPassword] cant work.so I have to reset password.
create a init file with contents like this

> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');

place it in any directory easy to find,such as Desktop

> mysqld --init-file=[YourInitFile] &

many logs printed on your screen.

> mysql -uroot -pMyNewPass

enjoy your high-version mysql!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me because I was actually switching from MariaDB to Mysql.
Switching back to MariaDB solved this.

I'm guessing the existing database wasn't compatible.

Comment: This was also my issue, I was switching from MariaDB to MySQL. But switching back to MariaDB wasn't an acceptable solution.
I removed the new mysql `brew uninstall mysql@8.0` then deleted the old mysql folder created by MariaDB `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql` (this will delete your databases obviously). Then `brew install mysql@8.0` and `mysql.server start` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`
Thanks to Matteo Alessani

Answer (score -2):

While Installing from source,please follow the instruction in file `INSTALL-SOURCE`

where installation instruction are given in `section 2.8`

after installation ,check are there any process running of mysql
with ps aux | grep  mysql

You'll find like this

```
root      1817  0.0  0.0 108336  1228 ?        S    Jan21   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mail.gaurav.local.pid
mysql     2141  0.0  1.2 497660 24588 ?        Sl   Jan21   0:26 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mail.gaurav.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mail.gaurav.local.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
root      5659  0.0  0.0 103256   840 pts/13   S+   11:30   0:00 grep mysql
```

`kill` all process related to `mysql`,and then try to start mysql server

Comment: the question said BREW

Answer (score -3):

First `mv -f /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak` and try the command `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --ldata=[destination]` replace the destination with the data directory, after that start the MySQL with `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: There is no /etc/init.d/mysql on Mac OS X!