# The server quit without updating the PID File - Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos

I've been following this guide for the setup of my AMP stack:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

and I'm having trouble setting up MySQL on my Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

I can't seem to start the server, gives me an error of "The server quit without updating the PID file"
I have been following the solutions on these guides to no avail:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/ 
[After MySQL install via Brew, I get the error - The server quit without updating PID file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating)

**Solutions I've tried:**

- Straight up server restart using ***/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart*** also manually on the preferences pane, accompanied with MacBook restarts
- Reinstalled to MySQL's latest version (***mysql-5.6.26-osx10.9-x86_64***)
- Removed the .err files, and to recreated the missing PID file it's looking for (no avail, deletes the recreated PID file and still generates .err)
- chmod -755 on the ***/usr/local/mysql/*** to relax its permissions

Please help. Anything else I may have missed?

Comment: Be careful with permissions. If `/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin` is world-writable, you're [one step closer to full server compromise through a simple SQL injection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_plugin_dir). This directory should be read-only, or writable only for the `root` user (and by all means, not by the `mysql` user).

Comment: @zneak I just followed that instruction from the guide I was copying, seemed to solve the problem for some, you're right it's a pretty unsecure method and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have multiple processes running of mysql.  Open Activity Monitor and search for "mysqld".  Quit all the processes and restart mysql.  If that does not work, try killing the process in terminal:

```
sudo kill -15 {PID}
```