# How to install MySQL on Mavericks/Mac (10.9.2) correctly?

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have spent overnight to get mysql working on my Mac. I am stuck in the following loop:

```
iMAC:~ admin$ brew install mysql
Warning: mysql-5.6.16 already installed

iMAC:~ admin$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMAC.local.pid).

iMAC:~ admin$ mysql.server restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/iMAC.local.pid).

iMAC:~ admin$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
homebrew.mxcl.mysql: Already loaded

iMAC:~ admin$ brew uninstall mysql
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.16...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.16

iMAC:~ admin$ brew uninstall mysql --force
Uninstalling mysql...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.16
```

Any clues how to make it work?

Comment: I think this belongs on askdifferent or superuser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These questions seems related and the answers there might help you:

1. [PID error on mysql.server start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start)
2. [After MySQL install via Brew, I get the error - The server quit without updating PID file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating?lq=1)