# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have installed MySQL server and trying to connect to it, but getting the error:

```
    Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have checked my /tmp directory and there is no mysql.sock. I can't find mysql.sock anywhere. I read that it might be in

```
    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But I checked there as well and there is even no mysql directory, only some postfix thing inside /lib.  Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I'm working on Mac OS X

Comment: Hello, can you paste the command you are using to connect? Also have you started MySQL?

Comment: @MarkButler I'm using this command: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: right, it's just the server wasn't running. However, I can not still understand where is mysql.sock, might there be any other hidden places where it may reside?

Comment: This error is very general, and it can be for a variety of reasons. For a neat summary see here: https://medium.com/@7anac/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-ce320ff75828

Comment: For me, instead of connecting it using `mysql`, connecting via host configuration like noted here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658142/1612469 I was able to connect to the database

Answer (score 304):

Try to start the MySQL server:

`mysql.server start`

Comment: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Comment: @wegginho Possible solution to your error message if you installed MySQL via homebrew [PID error on mysql server start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start)

Comment: forgot  start mysql services!

Comment: @bastianwegge try checking the error file in /usr/local/var/mysql/USERNAME.local.err in my case I had to delete /tmp/mysql.sock then restart using `mysql.server start`

Answer (score 64):

I got the same question after updating OS X Yosemite, well the solution is quite simple, check system preference -> mysql, the status was STOP. Just restart it and it works fine on my mac now.

Comment: Thanks a ton @keren so simple, i wasted a good 45 minutes on changing settings in my my.cnf file when the whole time this was the only problem.

Comment: Worked for me too thanks, was not having idea in terms DMG installation.

Comment: Um, what? Why would OSX's System Preferences have a MySQL option?

Comment: After you install MySQL (or at least after I install MySQL from their website) it shows up at the bottom of the system preferences next to Java and any other 3rd party preference options.

Comment: Didn't work at first, worked after a OS restart. Thanks!!

Comment: There's a MySQL option in System Preferences if you have MySQL Workbench installed.

Answer (score 48):

For MAMP

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

From https://coderwall.com/p/w5kwzw/solved-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock

UPDATE:
Every time my computer restarts I have to enter this command, so I created a shortcut.

Do the following in terminal type:

```
~: vi ~/.profile
```

Add

```
alias ...='source ~/.profile'
alias sockit='sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock'
```

Save.

In terminal type:

`~: ...` to source the .profile config.

Now in terminal you can just type

```
~: sockit
```

Comment: Awesome. Just the fix I was looking for.

Comment: I've came back to this post multiple times and it always works.

Comment: Upgraded to mysql 5.7.1 outside of MAMP and ran into the error. This fixed it for me

Comment: If you are on a mac book and you se MAMP this works

Answer (score 36):

Following command resolved my issue:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: After searching for 3 hours this solved my problem.
I just installed mysql through homebrew with `brew install mysql` but nothing of the commands homebrew told me to run worked properly. This made every problem go away... Thank you!! What exactly is that first line that you wrote? What does it mean?

Comment: Thanks, Works fine !

Comment: Hey for me it was: sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data

Comment: chown -R change the owner -R recursively

Comment: A pristine 10.13.1 and homebrew gave this error when installing mariadb (10.2.10). This owner change fixed it, so now `sudo brew services start mariadb`also works to start mariadb at boot (not just at login). YAY! Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

After trying all solutions it worked only for me after specifying the host

```
mysql -u root -p -h127.0.0.1
```

when asking for password

```
Enter password:
```

press enter

and it will work , if everything is ok as above .

Comment: I setup mysql with a docker container by using Docker for Mac, and map its 3306 port to Mac. Without adding the `-h 127.0.0.1`, it always prompt `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`; after adding the argument, it works well.

Comment: This is because going through 127.0.0.1 doesn't use the socket, I think. More of a narrow workaround.

Comment: Running `mysql -u root -h127.0.0.1`  without the `-p` flag worked for me, since when i installed MySQL I never ran the `mysql_secure_installation` command.  My understanding is that in this case the installation defaults to no required password.

Answer (score 14):

After struggling for hours the only thing which worked was

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

Then do a secure installation with

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Then connect to the db via

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Mysql is installed via homebrew and the version is

```
Server version: 5.7.21 Homebrew
```

Specifying the version might be helpful as the solution may be different based upon the version.

Answer (score 13):

Try this it worked for me.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: Why this path? while using "where is mysql" command(MAC OS) giving output /usr/local/mysql/bin/.How to identify this path in Mac?

Comment: Ya , The path changes accordingly

Answer (score 10):

In your mysql config file, which is present in `/etc/my.cnf` make the below changes and then restart `mysqld` dameon process

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

As well check this related thread

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock)

Comment: there's no my.cnf file in /etc directory. I think I can create that file manually, but as I said there is no mysql directory in /var/lib, how can the socket be there?

Comment: Check the related thread I have posted as well as check whether your mysql server is actually running or not.

Comment: I found the file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: if you installed with brew you need to use `/tmp/mysql.sock` as the sock location

Answer (score 8):

Following resolved my issue:

Check where is your MySQL server is listning to: netstat -nlp
If it is listning to TCP then use 127.0.0.1 while connecting to DB instead of "localhost"

Check MySQL doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Comment: this seems to work for me and proves mysql is alive but why can I not connect to local socket?

Answer (score 7):

First Type this-:

```
brew services start mysql
```

Then this -:

```
mysql -uroot
```

Answer (score 5):

Type in the terminal as follows:

```
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XAMPP in Mac OS X and have installed MySQL with Homebrew you may have this problem. In XAMPP manager window go to Manage Servers and select MySQL, then click configure and open the configuration file, there you have the socket file path, put the path in your MySQL host config and it should work.

It's something like this:

```
...
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
...
```

then, for instance in Django:

```
...    
DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
            "NAME": "database_name",
            "USER": "user",
            "PASSWORD": "password",
            "HOST": "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock",
            "PORT": "",
        }
    }
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

First, knowing where the data directory was for me was the key. `/usr/local/var/mysql`
In here, there was at least one file with extension .err preceded with my local machine name. It had all info i needed to diagnose.

I think i screwed up by installing mysql 8 first. My app isn't compatible with it so i had to downgrade back to 5.7

My solution that worked for me was going to 
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf

Find this line if its there. I think its mysql 8 related:

```
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Remove it because in the mysql 5.7 says it doesnt like it in the error log

Also add this line in there if its not there under the bind-address.

```
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Go to the `/tmp` directory and delete any mysql.sock files in there. On server start, it will recreate the sock files

Trash out the data directory with mySQL in the stopped state. Mine was  `/usr/local/var/mysql` . This is the same place where the logs are at

From there i ran

```
>mysqld --initialize
```

Then everything started working...this command will give you a random password at the end. Save that password for the next step

Running this to assign my own password.

```
>mysql_secure_installation
```

Both

```
>brew services stop mysql@5.7
```

and

```
>mysql.server start
```

are now working. Hope this helps. It's about 3 hours of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Stoping and starting the mysql server from terminal resolved my issue.
Below are the cmds to stop and start the mysql server in MacOs.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Note:
Restarting the services from Mac System preference didn't resolve the issue in my mac.  So try to restart from terminal.

Comment: If MySQL is installed using brew, just run mysql.server start

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue while taking mysql dump:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock

Try to give the path for mysql.sock explicitly.

1. **type ps -ef|grep -mysql**

   Get the path for mysql.sock from this command, e.g /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
2. **mysqldump --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.dump -u username -pPassword**

   you can try this with any mysql command

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS, the file to init mysql is located here:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent lots of time doing this
I want to put my django app on my server and when I run `python manage.py migrate` I met this questions

And!! I set this
`ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock` 
It worked finally!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Here is how I have fixed it.

Step 1: Remove mysql using command:

```
brew uninstall --force mysql
```

Step 2: Run command `brew doctor` which will give you some hint related to your brew packages.

Step 3: Cleanup brew packages using command:

```
brew cleanup
```

Step 4: Move/delete previously installed mysql data using command:

```
mv /usr/local/var/mysql/ /usr/local/var/old_mysql
```

Step 5: Finally install mysql again using command:

```
brew install mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I start mysql from settings,it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart MySql server using

`brew services stop mysql@5.7`

if even after this issue is not resolved then try following command

`brew postinstall mysql@5.7`

if you gets following error -

```
2023-06-18T09:23:53.239569Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-06-18T09:23:53.241698Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2023-06-18T09:23:53.241717Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

then please delete mySql directory. Search location of your file on Google. In my case it was `/usr/var/mysql`

Answer (score -2):

If you're running on a macOS it's just easier to first check go to 'System Preferences' and see if MySQL is running or not.