# ruby wont connect with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying to get it to work with MySQL. I installed mysql using brew install mysql then I installed  gem mysql2 but nothing works. I have went through all the questions on here and nothing seems to work. here is my database.yml

```
    # MySQL.  Versions 5.0+ are recommended.
      #
      # Install the MYSQL driver
      #   gem install mysql2
      #
      # Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
      #   gem 'mysql2'
      #
      # And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
      #   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
      #
      default: &default
        adapter: mysql2
        encoding: utf8
        pool: 5
        username: root
        password:
        host: localhost

      development:
        <<: *default
        database: optimus_development

      # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
      # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
      # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
      test:
        <<: *default
        database: optimus_test

      # As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
      # like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
      # ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
      #
      # Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
      # the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
      # for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
      # production deployment.
      #
      # On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
      # available as an environment variable. For example:
      #
      #   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
      #
      # You can use this database configuration with:
      #
      #   production:
      #     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
      #
      production:
        <<: *default
        database: optimus_production
        username: optimus
        password: <%= ENV['OPTIMUS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

this is the error that i get when I try to run it in the browser:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have tried changing changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 but that doesn't work. Any Assistance would be appreciated

I after reading a possible duplicate link below I started my server and now I am getting this message:

```
          Unknown database 'optimus_development'Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
```

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: Please always post the errors you get.

Comment: One common issue with local MySQL services is that they are running on a Unix socket whose file is not in the default expected location, requiring you to add a `socket: /path/to/mysql.sock` in the database.yml

Comment: And, you said you did `brew install mysql` but did you actually start the MySQL server, and can you connect to it from the command line, without Rails?

Comment: Michael Berkowski, wher do I add "socket: /path/to/mysql.sock"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436028/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock-2)

Comment: should I delete my MAMP?

Comment: @EdBanes If you're using homebrew, MAMP is redundant. Did you follow the instructions that `brew info mysql` shows?

Comment: Hey infused went to the link started my server and now I am getting this:                                                Unknown database 'optimus_development'Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your MySQL server is started:

```
Apple Menu > System Preferences > MySQL > Start MySQL Server
```

Comment: Mysql isn't even showing in the system preferences window. Is this because I already had mamp installed and it's interfering with the mysql installed by brew?

Comment: This is only relevant if you've used the MySQL installer with Preference Pane extension.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to run mysql server from the terminal using "mysql.server start". Then I had to run  "bin/rake db:create db:migrate" and it worked after that