# PDO can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Our school let us sue a small database that I am trying to access through the school network.
Connecting using

```
mysql -D ddddd -h hhhh -u uuuu
```

works fine (Note that contrary to multiple questions on this site, hhhh is *not* localhost). However, using

```
new PDO('mysql:host=hhhh;dbname=dddd, uuuu, pppp)
```

does not, and brings up an error:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock''
```

How do I locate this socket? (NB: In case it is relevant, the schools computers run on FreeBSD and I only have a very limited permissions).

Comment: May be this help you :-  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436028/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock-2)  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)  [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock''
```

means that the PDO is trying to connect to MySQL via local socket (linux socket is file).

But my guess is that you want to connect via hostname/ip. Your code Has to be wrong. From the example it looks like you are using php. Try double check everything.

Here is an example from php.net:

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had seen the example from php.net. What bugs me is that this example specifically uses 127.0.0.1. Does host=... really works with a hostname? Or should I find mysql.sock and use something like unix-socket=... ?

Comment: php PDO libraby should definitely work with hostnames, there has to be error somewhere, can you post your code somewhere like pastebin.com ? (clear passwords before posting)

Comment: So I am not exactly sure what caused the issue, but I think it was because I used dbname=... before host=... Anyway, it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use correct IP address to connect.

If u r using localhost then by default socket will be used on Linux so
Use 127.0.0.1 as host instead of localhost.

Comment: I see this happening on Windows 10 too, maddening.