# how to reset my mysql password in mac os 10.13.3

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I forgot the password I used when I installed it
so, I can not access to the server now. 
I tried deleting the MySQL and install it again but it didn't show the password again.
So I tried to do it by the terminal and this is the result ...
first i stopped the MySQL server
[image: first]

then i put `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables` in the terminal

[image: second]

after that in new terminal window i wrote `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
\q`

the result was "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

[image: third]

these are all the commands

[image: fourth]

Comment: You should include the errors or result of your command as text, not give an external link.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command. I believe you should have mysql running. If that doesn't work try with mysql stopped.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Hopefully should get you to prompt a password change.

Also, for the socket error, you can try following this link.
[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436028/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock-2)

Answer (score 4):

You can try reseting the root password by running MySQL in Safe Mode.

Here are the steps:

1. Stop MySQL:

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
2. Start it in safe mode:

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, and..

3. Log in without a password as root:

   `mysql -u root`
4. Update root (and any other user's) password)

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
   \q`
5. Restart MySQL in normal mode

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Reference: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

Note: this is pretty standard reset procedure, but just documented better in the above guide compared to mysql reference docs.