# mysql.server restart gives error message

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I get the following odd error when I try doing a restart with MySQL:

```
$ sudo mysql.server stop
Password:
Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS! 
$ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS! 
$ sudo mysql.server restart
Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS! 
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/my.local.pid).
```

I had a look at the answer here: [PID error on mysql.server start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start)

but I get the following errors:

```
$ mysql_install_db
FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you could try :

- try a straight restart:

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

- remove /etc/my.cnf (or rename it) and restart:

`sudo mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.bak`

`sudo mysql.server restart`

- remove any .err files or create missing .pid mentionned in the error message (this one worked for me)

`rm *.err /usr/local/mysql/data/`

`rm /usr/local/var/mysql/*.err`

- simple mysql reinstall

Hope one of those does it for you !

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is a permissions issue. Try solving it with this command:

`$ sudo chown _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/*`

or

`$ sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`

It might also be that the mysql folder has a permissions issue:

`$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/`