# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file launching mysql.server start

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed mysql 5.7.21 with brew on my HighSierra mac, but when I launch mysql.server start I get the error

```
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/myMac.pid)
```

I followed this guide https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e, and I also tried to solve the issue how described in all the posts on this argument:

- I gave 777 permissions to mysql folder
- I deleted the .err file with

  > sudo rm /usr/local/var/mysql/myMac.err
- I created the .pid file with

  > sudo nano /usr/local/var/mysql/myMac.pid
- I tried every step of this post [PID error on mysql.server start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444861/pid-error-on-mysql-server-start)

but nothing worked.
I've already completely unistalled mysql several times after the first vain time, also without brew, but nothing changed.

Do you please have any idea?

Comment: You probably need to look at the full log to understand why it fails.